# Update Wordpress 4.7.5 to 4.8 caused datepicker shows wrongly

Tags: datepicker

Update Wordpress 4.7.5 to 4.8 caused data picker problem

hi-sky.net

before updating I used google jquery libraries to avoid userpro conflict

but after updating , stopped userpro and use google jquery libraries plugins, the data picker still problem

Comment: Do you mean datepicker? What did you do to debug conflicts. Please provide as many details as possible, and put it into your question.

Comment: yes datepicker shows wrongly [link](http://hi-sky.net)

Comment: before updating I installed userpro plugin, that conflicted with date picker, I found solution by installing use google library plugin , it worked fine , after updating, google library wont work any more disabling or enabling it no any effects

Comment: by the way I removed userpro plugin many issues with wordpress 4.8, even though the problem of date picker still

Comment: opps ..the problem was from yith booking plugin replaced data picker js file with other ,, now is solved !!!

Comment: @HiSky glad you solved it and thanks for reporting back. Would you please post your findings as an answer, then revisit this page in a couple of days to accept it by clicking the checkmark? This will close your question and will help keep the site tidy. Thank you, and welcome to WPSE.